# Azure Easy Tables missing and duplicate data when paging

Tags: c#, database, azure

I have a REST call to pull all the data from a small (145 rows) EasyTable used for an Azure based application.

When pulling the data, the response indicates I need to page to collect all the data.  It returns data in chunks of 50 rows at a time.  The code below collects the responses until no more data is returned.  When I run it, the first response gives me 50 unique rows and includes a `$top=950&$skip=50` field for the subsequent call.  However, when I make that call, it also returns 50 rows, but some are duplicates of the first 50 rows.  It continues like this until I get 145 rows, but since some are duplicates, I am missing some rows, and have some redundant rows.

The data in the table is constant during all the calls, it only changes every few days, and I confirmed it did not change during any of my testing.

I am aware I can re-factor and simplify the code, but I can't find anything that should be causing my issue.  Any pointers where to look?

I tried using a `$filter` and changing the `$top=200`, but the only thing that works is to ensure the filter never returns more than 50 rows.  Unfortunately, since the data can change, setting up a series of calls to do that would require an extra field just to query against.  I'll do that in the end if I need to, but it seems the paging should work.

```
private string AzureTablesStandardGet(string tableURL, string queryString)
{
    GetAzuremysite();
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    string uriQueryString = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(queryString);
    string sURL = string.Format("https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables{0}?{1}", tableURL, uriQueryString);

    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
    wrGETURL.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    wrGETURL.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    wrGETURL.Headers.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0"); 
    wrGETURL.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", mysite.access_token);   
    wrGETURL.ContentType = "application/json;odata=nometadata";
    wrGETURL.Method = "GET";
    ((HttpWebRequest)wrGETURL).Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    ((HttpWebRequest)wrGETURL).CookieContainer = cookieJar;

    string sLine = "";

    var mine = "first";
    try
    {
        while (mine.Equals("first") || mine.ToLower().Contains("rel=next"))
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrGETURL.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string newLine = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                sLine += newLine;
            }
            mine = httpResponse.GetResponseHeader("Link");
            if (mine.ToLower().Contains("rel=next"))
            {
                string newURL = mine.Split(';')[0];
                newURL = newURL.Split('?')[1];
                sURL = string.Format("{0}?{1}", sURL.Split('?')[0], newURL);
                wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
                ((HttpWebRequest)wrGETURL).CookieContainer = cookieJar;
                wrGETURL.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
                wrGETURL.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                wrGETURL.Headers.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
                wrGETURL.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", mysite.access_token); 
                wrGETURL.ContentType = "application/json;odata=nometadata";
                ((HttpWebRequest)wrGETURL).Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
                wrGETURL.Method = "GET";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        sLine = sLine.Replace("][",",");
        return sLine;
    }
}
}
```

So, as an example, the first call would be something like:

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?$top=1000
```

and the second, based on the response in the Link header:

header = `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/?%24top=950&%24skip=50; rel=next`

GET call = `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=950&%24skip=50`

I tried making the first call

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?$top=1000&$skip=0
```

but it does not make a difference

---

**Update 2018-04-26**

Changing the code to manually index through the table 50 items at a time returns all data without any duplicates.  Now I am really confused.

This sequence of calls returns 145 items, but some are duplicates, thus not all data is returned. Note that while I am requesting more than 50 rows per request, the server only returns 50 rows and a **Link** header indicating not all data was returned, and it includes the parameters I should use to get the rest of the data.

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=1000   
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=950&%24skip=50
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=900&%24skip=100
```

No fourth call required since I use the Link rel=next not present, which means stop asking for data

This series of calls returns all data without any duplicates

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=50&%24skip=0
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=50&%24skip=50
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=50&%24skip=100
```

However, it requires a fourth call, that returns an empty array "[]", which I use to indicate I've collected all the information and I can stop.

```
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable?%24top=50&%24skip=150
```

Since `$top=xx` means how many items to return in total, not per page, the calls should return the same results, but they do not.

Comment: If I try to manually index through the table asking for 50 rows at a time until I get an empty array, it returns all data and no duplicates. 
 I am now really confused why these series of calls return different results.
 I updated the question to show that